# Getting resource id by dropping external events

Tags: javascript, jquery, resources, fullcalendar

I am having trouble with full calendar. I have 3 resources and some external events. When I drop an external event I want to have the resource id from which I dropped my event.

But when I do this:

```
drop: function(date, allDay, resource) { 

    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
    var cObj = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
    var resource = cObj.resource.id;
    console.log(resource + '<---- RESOURCE');
```

I get "undefined" back in my console.

Do I have to define resource id in the eventObject? And yes, how?

Are people here who knows a solution for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
drop: function (date, allDay, ev, ui, res) {
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

    var resource = res; 
    console.log(resource);
}
```

Variable 'res' is the resource where to your event has been dragged.
Use 'console.log(resource)' to see what attributes the resource has. (resource.id or resource.Id for example)

Note: It's important to use all the 5 params in the drop function!

Comment: It has a name, a visstart and visend and an end and several functions, but no resource id or something like that

Comment: Which resource calendar do you use?

Comment: http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/  this is the resource view fullcalendar I use

Comment: That variable gives me the start from my agenda. Gives me the name from which view I use. Not my resources.

Comment: console.log(ev) or console.log(ui) also results in nothing?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you because i use a different resource calendar